# Adding CC to contact form plugin

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, emails

I'm trying to edit the Contact Form plugin to copy the email to another address.

Looking in apps/models/EmailModel.php I see this for CC:

```php
'cc' => array(AttributeType::Mixed);
```

Looking in apps/services/EmailService.php I see this:

```php
// Add any CC's
if (!empty($emailModel->cc))
{
    foreach ($emailModel->cc as $cc)
    {
        if (!empty($cc['email']))
        {
            $ccEmail = $cc['email'];

            $ccName = !empty($cc['name']) ? $cc['name'] : '';
            $email->addCC($ccEmail, $ccName);
        }
    }
}
```

So, it looks like 'cc' needs to be array? I tried it without it being an array and I get an invalid foreach error. At the moment, I've added this line to ContactFormService.php (after line 45):

```php
$email->cc = array('email' => 'name@domain.com');
```

I've also tried this:

```php
$email->cc = array('email' => 'name@domain.com', 'name' => 'My Name');
```

The problem: The email is not being CC'd and I'm not getting any errors. Anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From that code snippet, it looks like you're needing nested arrays. Try setting your `$email->cc` property like this.

```
$email->cc = array(
    array('name' => 'Your Name', 'email' => 'name@example.com')
);
```

The code snippet is iterating over `$email->cc as $cc` as the first array, then going into `cc['name']` and `cc['email']` as a nested array.