# P&T Contact Form plugin: How can I copy "name" and "email address" in the body of the mail?

Tags: plugin-contactform

I'm currently working with the [Contact Form plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm/) from P&T. I don't need much more, but as usual the client wants to:

- See the email address and name in the body of the mail (he won't understand the way it works now).

Is there a way to get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up hacking the ContactFormService.php file with some extra code for the body

It's actually quite simple:

$email->body = "Sender: ".$message->fromName."\n\nEmail-addreas: ".$message->fromEmail."\n\nMessage: ".$message->message;

Same thing for cc mail

I understood 2.2 will have a plugin hook for this kind of added functionality (emails.onBeforeSend event)

Answer (score 2):

Your options are either:

1) Hack the plugin to get it to add name and email to the body.

2) Use a more robust [form-building plugin](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/sprout-forms).

3) Use JavaScript to add a hidden input to the page that will add it to the body so they don't have to enter an email twice.  Something like:

```
<input id="emailCopy" type="hidden" name="message[emailCopy]" value="my@email.com">
```

Comment: This would be a great use-case for a plugin-hook.

Comment: @VictorIn Yup... not a bad idea.

Comment: I've had all three options in my mind. Was hoping there would be some functionality available (the sprout plugin might be to much and is still in development). I've seen  a hack here, http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/376/adding-cc-to-contact-form-plugin that might help a bit. A hook would be better yes, as a designer I'm not sure if that fits my bill

Comment: I've managed to hack the plugin so that it shows the sender and name. I've asked a developer to do this with a plugin hook, but that appears not to be possible. He needs an added emails.onBeforeSend event to the event list to do that. Is there a way that can be done (feature request I think?)