# Contact Form: Name and Email in Message Body

Tags: plugin-contactform

This is a follow-up to an earlier question from 2014: [P&T Contact Form plugin: How can I copy “name” and “email address” in the body of the mail?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1400/pt-contact-form-plugin-how-can-i-copy-name-and-email-address-in-the-body-o) ... it seems that Craft (and the plugin) has gone through significant updates since that question was answered.

How would I include `fromName` and `fromEmail` into the body of the message?

I read about events in the documentation, but it doesn't say where they go. Do I put those into the craft>config>contactform.php file? How would I setup an event to handle that inclusion?

Comment: What context do you wan to include it? Do you want to say "Message from Jeff his email is "jeff@email.com" and then show the contents of the body?

Or do you want to inject the to/email within the body of the message?
For example, if Jeff had a message of "Hey i like your site [Jeff] [jeff@email.com] have a great day". 

Who would get this email? The admin or the user as a confirmation email?

Comment: I’m trying to use it as a basic signup form. I edited the config file to allow for recipients to be controlled from the template as an entry... I would be okay if just fromName and fromEmail passed through onto the message body

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out by duplicating the field...

```
<input id="fromName" type="text" name="fromName" 
value="{% if message is defined %}{{ message.fromName }}{% endif %}">
{{ message is defined and message ? errorList(message.getErrors('fromName')) }}
<input type="hidden" id="fullName" name="message[Full Name]" class="fullName">
```

Then duplicating the single entry to the hidden with some Javascript...

```
    $('#fromName').bind('keypress keyup blur', function() {
      $('#fullName').val($(this).val());
    });
```

It parses through to the email message as:

Full Name: First Last